# Chrome version 45.0.2454.85

Tags: google-chrome, agent

One function of my website is not executed when the users uses Chrome / 45.0.2454.85.
This is the user agent:
Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36

any help is welcome!Thank you!

Comment: Any more information? What function, what's the error message?

Comment: Just a simple function.No errors show on error_log or debug.log.Something very strange!

Answer (score 0):

I detected the problem. some users disable javascrip from browser settings! That functions was in js.I don't understand why they disables Java?!.I check if js is disable,is so, i show a message "javascript turned off" and i don't show the website content until they enable js!